# Function as sum of two periodic functions

Tags: real-numbers, periodic-functions

Can an arbitrary function from the real numbers to the real numbers can be expressed as the sum of two periodic functions?

Comment: The answer is no. How can you describe unbounded functions like $f(x)=x^3$ by periodic functions?

Comment: @Crostel: there are periodic unbounded functions, such as $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is an integer and $f(x)=\tan(\pi x)$ otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the example of $\exp(x)$. Suppose that $\exp(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, with $f$ periodic of period $u>0$, and $g$ periodic with period $v>0$.

Then we have $\exp(x+u)=f(x)+g(x+u)$ and hence $\exp(u)(f(x)+g(x))=f(x)+g(x+u)$.

This show that $(\exp(u)-1) f(x)=g(x+u)-\exp(u)g(x)$ and hence as $g(x+u)$ and $g(x)$ are periodic with period $v$, $f$ is periodic with period $v$.

In the same way, $g$ is periodic with period $u$, and $\exp(x)$ is periodic with period $u+v>0$, contradiction.

Comment: +1 This might benefit from (a) some whitespace between successive points; (b) replacement of $\exp(x)$ by a more general $h(x)$; and (c) spelling out that $g(x+u)$ and $-h(u)g(x)$ are each periodic with period $v$ so their sum $(h(u)-1)f(x)$ also is, ensuring $f(x)$ is.  But otherwise this seems correct

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comments. For a more general function $h$, I think that you have supposed $h(x+u)=h(x)h(u)$, so again an exponential...

Comment: You may be right